# Use GAWK as native function in Java (JNI)

Tags: java, c, awk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build the GAWK library (c language) as a dll file so I could access it directly from my Java code, without needing to execute an external process (as a "native" function).

As it's easy to do the ["helloWorld" JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-2.1), it's quite complicated to do it with GAWK source code, especially for one who isn't familiar with C language.

I need help with 2 things:

1. How to properly build the complication environment
2. How to recognize
   the place in the code where I should write my "doAwk" function (I
   got lost in their code)

Or, if you're familiar with a place where I can find an already working version of it - that would be the best :)

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be simpler to implement the features you need in Java. It would also avoid the GPL contamination of your app.

Comment: Why not calling it as an external process? Gawk reads from stdin and writes to stdout, that is much simpler to exchange with your Java program than converting each function parameter and response type. Also troubleshooting would be easier because you can execute the command of doubt manually.

Comment: @Olivier, it actually won't by simpler... I need fully functional AWK... now.. there is a java lib for it, but it performs way worst than the c version... so implementing in java is, unfortunately, not an option... :(

Comment: @Stefan, 
I can call it as an external process, this is actually what I do right now... the problem is that it doesn't do a great job when dealing with heavy loads... 
I assume that invoking it in process will make it much better in heavy loads..

Comment: Ok, I understand. But don't forget that awk is a scripting language. You can save the loading time of the script interpreter but I assume that most of the execution time will be the same.

Comment: Even if feasible, that's not a simple project. You'll have to transform a program mean to be standalone (which keeps a lot of state into static variables) into a reentrant interpreter. That sounds like a lot of fun with preprocessor wizardry. Why not use [perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html), where that whole work has already been done? Except for some sweet features like regex RS, perl can do everything gawk can. There even used to be an awk -> perl translator ;-)

Comment: All of your comments are highly appreciated, and helped me a lot building a strategy.
Indeed, it seems like a very complicated project (I started doing it, and realized that it's way more complicated than I thought, because all the reason that you already mentioned).
For now, I will probably go with executing it in a process, using a Semaphore that will block too many executions in parallel. 
Perl seems like a good option in the near future, it looks like it has intuitive Java interface (will need to dig a little dipper into it).

Thank you very much for all of your comments!